# Stop Android for killing my Activity after 30 minutes from background

Tags: android, service, android-activity, notifications, kill

I am creating an application where there is an activity which contains a timer running when ever user comes to that screen. If user leaves that screen by pressing home button without stopping the timer then the user is notified by the notification and then if the user again come back to the app from any means then the same screen should appear.

It is working fine if the user comes back to the screen before 30 minutes. Because after 30 minutes android kills my activity from background and my application starts from beginning.

I want to stop android for killing my activity from background. Please help if any body has any idea...

Thanks.

How can i link an Activity to a service? So that when Android OS tries to destroy my activity then it won't let it do because my activity is linked with the running service.

Comment: Can you use a Service, Broadcast Receiver, or just pass session data to the app via the Notications intent?

Comment: Are you saying that restart activity with the data saved in notification for the recreation?

Comment: Yes, if you are just showing some text/numbers, you can store them in the intent (please note, afaik, you're limited to about 1MB of data).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Services](http://%20%20Use%20Services%20to%20doing%20background%20work.%20In%20this%20case%20Activity%20should%20be%20like%20a%20simple%20UI%20facade%20linked%20to%20Service.) to doing background work. In this case Activity should be like a simple UI facade linked to Service.

Comment: I am using a Service to send notification but can you please elaborate how can i link my activity with my service?

Comment: How can i link an Activity to a service? So that when Android OS tries to destroy my activity then it won't let it do because my activity is linked with the running service.