# Android for killing Activity after 30

Tags: android, android-activity

I have read this question here [Stop Android for killing my Activity after 30 minutes from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373643/stop-android-for-killing-my-activity-after-30-minutes-from-background)

about when a background process is killed after 30 min. I have created a simple App with a thread and i put it to background but after an hour or so thread would still be running.

So when an app gets killed after a 30 min?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android manages process with priority.

[Processes and Application Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle)

If your application haven't running service or foreground activity, your process has low priority. It means your application can be killed by Android anytime.

So, 30 minutes is meaningless duration. Your application can be running forever in background if memory pressure is low.

In advance, process priority is a one of condition to select killing candidate application by Android platform.

To reduces battery consumption, Google has added more strict condition to that.

foreground service that was introduced in Oreo is a one example.

[Background Service Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services)

To sum up, it depends on device Android version and status of memory pressure and so on.